# User's Email Parameter Not Been Persisted Into The Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a users model in a rails 4.1.8 application with the attributes `email` and `password`. I fired up rails console, `user = User.new(email: "user@example.com" , password: "example")` work but `user.save` saves the password and omits the email. below is the model, migrated database file and rails console log.

USER MODEL

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save {self.email = email.downcase! }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                         format:{with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, 
                         uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

DATABASE FILE (For the User)

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
     t.string :email, unique: true
     t.string :password_digest

     t.timestamps null: false
   end
  end
end
```

RAILS CONSOLE LOG

```
<r.new(email: "user@example.com" , password: "example")
=> #<User id: nil, email: "user@example.com", password_digest:         "$2a$10$jxwd/oriT
z2HklHK4b4nf.P.DWb6s35YTO.EbYwup0I...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):008:0> user.save
(1.0ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`email` =   'user@example.com' LIMIT 1
SQL (46.0ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `password_digest`,  `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-07-20 20:54:35', '$2a$10$jxwd/oriTz2HklHK4b4nf.P.DWb6s35YTO.Eb
Ywup0I.gMTOLSNKa', '2015-07-20 20:54:35')
(89.1ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

USERS CONTROLLER

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email)
    end
end
```

Looking at the log the email parameter was not inserted into; please, any help with this is appreciated.

Comment: What does the user_params (strong params) method in your users_controller.rb look like?

Comment: @MarsAtomic, I added my UsersController

Comment: @OpyOsegs Not enough for a compelte answer, but you need to include saving the object in the controller. For example, define the `create` method, and add logic like `if @user.save ...` You also do not define an `@user` object at all in the controller

Comment: @HunterStevens yes, the create method and others needs to be written but i'm trying to make it a test driven application.

Comment: Great job for writing tests before code. Just expect any tests to fail, as you do not have these methods written yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following in your `User` model:

```
before_save {self.email = email.downcase } # no "!"
```

`downcase!` edits the variable on which it is called and does not return the downcased string unless there is something to downcase (i.e., if you use it on an all lower-case email, it returns nil and based on your console output, this is what is happening). `downcase` alone should be fine.

[downcase! on the API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-downcase-21)

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm; and thanks for the API page.

Comment: No problem! Glad it's sorted out!